# Is this property equivalent to absolute continuity?

Tags: real-analysis

When thinking about the proof that every [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity) function has [Lusin property (N)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzin_N_property) (i.e., it maps [null sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set) to null sets) I had the feeling that this property might be useful:

> Let $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R$. I am interested in functions with the property that for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $a\le a_1\le b_1 \le \dots \le a_n \le b_n \le b$ and
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i)<\delta$$
>   then also 
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n |f(y_i)-f(x_i)|<\varepsilon$$
>   for any choice of $x_i,y_i\in [a_i,b_i]$.

This property implies absolute continuity, which is what we get for $x_i=a_i$ and $y_i=b_i$. Is this property equivalent to absolute continuity?

Comment: To clarify your observation here:  let $\omega f([c,d])$ denote the *oscillation* of $f$ on the interval $[c,d]$, i.e., $$\omega f([c,d]) = \sup \{|f(y)-f(x)|: c\leq x < y \leq d \}.$$  Then you have shown that the apparently stronger condition that $\sum_{i=1}^n \omega f([a_i,b_i]) < \epsilon$ does not in fact produce a stronger version of absolute  continuity.  Try the same thing with bounded variation.

Answer (score 1):

It is trivial that this is the same thing as absolute continuity. (I should have noticed this immediately.)

I can simply use that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i-x_i| \le \sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i) < \delta$$
and then use the definition of absolute continuity for the points $x_i$, $y_i$ to get $$\sum_{i=1}^n |f(y_i)-f(x_i)|<\varepsilon.$$